# Algorithmic approach to check wordlist phrase against MD5 hash

Tags: algorithms

Say I have an MD5 hash. I need to decrypt.

I also have a wordlist of 100.000 words, in an array.

I KNOW that the MD5 hash consists of 3 different words, all present in the array. I dont know which three words, and I dont know the order of the three words. The array is in alphabetic order. All I know for sure is, that the 3 words are present in the wordlist array.

I need to somehow come to a conclusion where i can hash the phrase of the 3 words, and check against the MD5 hash I have.

Doing a nested `for loop` design seems to be super slow, since I then take Word A, Word B and Word C - I check, and go to Word C+1 and Check, then Word C+2 and check.

This will take forever, and is curious to other design ideas.

Comment: Since the MD5 of A + B is different than the MD5 of A appended to the MD5 of B, there likely is not a more practical way to do this.

Comment: _"Doing a nested for loop design seems to be super slow"_ This is by design, exactly why hashing is used for security purposes. Though I suspect you are already aware of this, what you're effectively asking is how to brute force passwords.

Comment: A hash is not encrypted so you can't "decrypt" it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of secure hashes is that what you are trying to do cannot be done any other way than brute-force. If there was more efficient way to do it, then it won't be a good secure hash.

And while it is true that MD5 is no longer considered "secure", it doesn't mean there is simple way to break it.

What you are trying to do here is a simple attack on password hash with help of dictionary. If it was simple, then it wouldn't be a good way to store passwords.

Comment: Actually, MD5 is no longer considered secure against *collision attacks*. The OP is performing a *preimage attack*, which AFAIK, MD5 is not nearly as weak in. Collision == finding any two inputs with the same hash. Preimage == finding an input with a specific hash. Second-preimage == finding an input with the same hash as a specific other input.